# HTML 2 div's next to eachother but also centered

Tags: html, position, css-position

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8su7.png)
[CSS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2277.png)

I want the 2 "product" div's to be next to eachother.but them both in the middle
i tired float left, and text align center (in all kinds of combinations and under every .class related but noting worked

text align center puts them both in the center but underneath eachother
text align center, followed by float left, does the same, or puts them both left.

```
.articles{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.buy{ 
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.product{
    margin: 60px 0 60px 60px;
    float: left;
}

.product img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 10px solid tan;
}
```

I tied the combo:
" text-align: center;
float: left;        "
both under .articles and under .product

also tried splitting them
(e.g. text-align under articles, and float under product. and other ways around)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do this with flexbox. Try this code right here:

```
<style>
.leftside {
  background: #000599;
}
.rightside {
  background: #006999;
}
.leftside, .rightside {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: left;
}

@media ( min-width : 600px ){
  body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000599 50%, #006999 50%);
  }
    .flexbox {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    }
  .leftside,
  .rightside {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background: none;
  }
}
</style>    
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="leftside">
    <p>
      left
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside">
    <p>
      right
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).